# Specify 'mapreduce.jobtracker.hosts.filename' for a single MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

A few nodes have been added to the cluster. My M/R job is failing when it gets executed on any of them. The exact reason why remains unclear and it will take a few days until a solution is found, so I am looking for a temporary workaround.

Is there a way to exclude these nodes (`mapreduce.jobtracker.hosts.exclude.filename`) on the job level?
Or whitelist the old, working nodes (`mapreduce.jobtracker.hosts.filename`)?

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the following property to 2

```
<property>
<name>mapred.max.tracker.failures</name>
<value>2</value>
</property>
```

and it will fail the job 2 twice on those nodes and carry on else where

Comment: That's not exactly an answer to my question, but I am upvoting it anyway - adding `-D mapreduce.job.maxtaskfailures.per.tracker=1` lowers the number of times a M/R task attempts to use the problematic nodes.